# Extracting a specific header from HTTP response using Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I'm hoping to extract one custom header response from a site using the Javascript code below:

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script>
var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
if (this.readyState === 4) {
//console.log(this.responseText);
}
});
var URL = "http://somesite.xml/records"

xhr.open("GET", URL);
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic itworks");
xhr.send(data);
var xrecords = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Records");
console.log(xrecords);
</script>
</head>
```

Two questions:
1. What changes do I need to make to have the response pull the content of that custom header?
2. The content of the header is a number of records. How can ensure that the data type is a number?

EDIT: Turned out the issue I was having was because I wasn't using an async function. A snipped of my resolved code is below:

```
function selector(x){
function fooO(callback) {
    function overdue (x){ 
        return "tasks.json?responsible-party-ids="+x+"&filter=overdue";
    }
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://' + company + '.site.com/' + overdue(x),
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Place `var xrecords = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Records");
console.log(xrecords);`  within `readystatechange` callback function.

Comment: YAS! However, it appears that my response is text where I need the numeric value. I'm assuming that I'm boned on that as the server determines the data type? Or is there a way to convert it to a number?

Comment: You can convert a `javascript` `String` to `Number` using `parseInt()` or `+` operator or `Number()`. What is the value of `xrecords`?

Comment: Ah... I used var xrecords = Number(xrecords)+1 and got a correct result. So stoked. Thank you!!

Comment: @guest271314 if you care to make this an answer I can mark it correct. Thanks!